# How to write data to SSD fast with a Linux userland program

Tags: c, linux

I want to know how to write data on SSD as fast as possible on Linux userland program.

In my situation, the userland program is informed the physical memory address and data size, then the program writes the data from RAM to SSD as a File.

The catalog spec for SSDs is 3000 MB/s for sequential writes. However, if *mmap* is used to handle physical address, the write speed will never exceed 40 MB/s.

```c
void writeData_mmap(unsigned long long srcAddr, unsigned long srcSize){
    int     fd_src, fd_dst;
    void*   srcPtr;

    fd_src = open("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY|O_SYNC);
    srcPtr = mmap(NULL, ulSize, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd_src, srcAddr);
    close(fd_src);

    fd_dst = open("/mnt/ssd/test.dat", O_RDWR|O_CREAT);
    ftruncate(fd_dst, srcSize);
    
    // gettimeofday(start, PROT_NONE);
    write(fd_dst, srcPtr, srcSize);
    // gettimeofday(end, PROT_NONE);
    // 40 MB/s > (end - start) / srcSize

    close(fd_dst);
    munmap(srcPtr, srcSize);
}
```

For reference, if the source data is at the address specified by *malloc*, the write speed reaches over 2500 MB/s. I cannot use this method because I need to specify the source data by physical address.

```c
#define PAGE_SIZE (4096)
void writeData_malloc(unsigned long srcSize){
    int     fd_src, fd_dst;
    void*   srcPtr_Orig, srcPtr_Aligned;

    srcPtr_Orig = malloc(srcSize + PAGE_SIZE);
    srcPtr_Aligned = (void*)(((unsigned long long)srcPtr_Orig + (PAGE_SIZE - 1)) & ~(PAGE_SIZE - 1));

    fd_dst = open("/mnt/ssd/test.dat", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_DIRECT);
    ftruncate(fd_dst, srcSize);
    
    // gettimeofday(start, PROT_NONE);
    write(fd_dst, srcPtr_Aligned, srcSize);
    // gettimeofday(end, PROT_NONE);
    // 2500 MB/s < (end - start) / srcSize

    close(fd_dst);
    free(pucBuf_orig);
}
```

How can I write data to an SSD using physical address as fast as the *malloc* method?

Comment: Quite huge difference: 40 vs 2500.  The O_SYNC might cause some performance penalty. Removing of O_SYNC may cause other issues. But, could be interesting to see byte-rate without it.

Comment: how fast can you copy data from /dev/mem into a malloc buffer? what if you use read instead of mmap?

Comment: @SKi I tried without O_SYNC but no change. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @user253751 I tried using *read* to copy data from /dev/mem to malloc buffer. The result was about 1400 MB/s for the entire program. While this is the best method so far in terms of speed, it is not ideal as it uses extra bandwidth on the bus.

Comment: @user253751  Sorry, but the above is wrong: *read* from /dev/mem results in an error and no data is read from /dev/mem. So the result is meaningless.

Comment: Are you sure that writing from mmaped /dev/mem isn't also returning an error?

Comment: @user253751 Yes. I have checked the value and size of the written file and there is no error.

Comment: I did not emphasize this, but in the case where *malloc* is used, the *O_DIRECT* option is also used to open the file to be written to. This is one of the reasons for the fast write speed, but when using *mmap*, this option cannot be used because of an error.